# My jQuery alert() is not showing what is supposed, its including my index.php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a pagination that I did only with php, but now Im trying to do my pagination using ajax and some fade effects.

**I have this link** in my index.php to pass my BASE, that is my htttp://localhost/project url to jQuery:

```
<link rel="nofollow" title="base" href="<?php echo BASE; ?>" />
```

**Then I have my jQuery function that works when I click in my pagination link.:**

```
$(function(){
   base = $('link[title="base"]').attr('href');
   urlaction    = base+'/actions'; 
   alert(urlaction);   
$('#body-content').on('click','.paginator a',function(){    

        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            return false;
        }else{
            $('#body-content .paginator span').css({color:'#FFF','border-color':'#fff'});
            $('#body-content .paginator a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('atv');

            var url  = $(this).attr('href');
            var data = url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
            var data = url.substr(data);

            $('#body-content .news').fadeTo(500,'0.2');

            $.post(urlaction,{action:'article_pagination',page:data},function(pagination){              
                alert(pagination);
                $('html, body').delay(500).animate({scrollTop:$('h2').offset().top},500);
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#body-content').html(pagination);
                        $('#body-content .news').fadeTo(500,'1');
                },600);
            });         
        }   
        return false;
    });
});
```

If I alert my `alert(urlaction)` I get my localhost/project/actions, so its correct it is my url to my actions.php file.

But when I do my alert(pagination); I get my alert with all code that I have in my index.php inside alert box, so it seems that is not getting the correct path to my actions.php file. But The path is correct...

**Do you see what can be wrong here??**

My alert appears like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html...>
<html xlmlns>
```

....
and all my index.php content

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are missing the `$` before `BASE` and are seeing an error page alerted back to you with that info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim Withers, but base is a variable that Im creating to get my title href, to store my BASE in my variable base. So I dont need $

Comment: Where do you `define` `BASE`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer dccclassics. In my configs.php file, like this define('BASE','http://localhost/project');